# Data augmentation using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to do a simple data augmentation on my data using ImageDataGenerator. However, my generator is giving my distorted images due to the zoom parameter. I would like the random zoom to only zoom in on my data, and when it zooms in to apply the same zoom on the width and height (to avoid distorted image outputs).

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False, featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                         samplewise_center = True, samplewise_std_normalization=True,
                         rotation_range=180, width_shift_range=0, height_shift_range=0,
                         shear_range=0, zoom_range=0.4, fill_mode='reflect',
                        horizontal_flip=True, rescale=1./255)
```

For now, the resulting images are below.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6cZ0.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJth1.png)

Comment: AFAIK, doing augmentation using `ImageDataGenerator` gives a little control, instead use a custom data generator for applying such augmentation.

Comment: @M.Innat `ImageDataGenerator` has an argument `preprocessing_function` that lets you do virtually anything

Comment: Oh, yea, I totally forgot. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the library imgaug?
check here: https://github.com/aleju/imgaug
It is better compared to the keras IDG with added benifits

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is random cropping:

```
def random_crop(image):
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    random_array = numpy.random.random(size=4);
    w = int((width*0.5) * (1+random_array[0]*0.5))
    h = int((height*0.5) * (1+random_array[1]*0.5))
    x = int(random_array[2] * (width-w))
    y = int(random_array[3] * (height-h))

    image_crop = image[y:h+y, x:w+x, 0:3]
    image_crop = resize(image_crop, image.shape)
    return image_crop

# Data generator 
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=0.2,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             fill_mode='nearest',
                             preprocessing_function=random_crop)
```

Source [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3990#issuecomment-679111722).

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my issue perfectly!